# SWT resize dynamically scroll of composite

Tags: scroll, swt, scrollbar, expand, composite

I have created a composite which has three children - Composite 1, 2 and 3. The children try to recreate the functionality of expand items in an expandbar. I want to make my parent composite scrollable vertically, so that all children are visible when expanded. I also want the size of the scroll to be changed dynamically as the composite gets bigger because it is possible to expand only one item, or two, or all three of them (see pictures for demonstration). How can I achieve that? Thanks in advance.

[image: not expanded]

[image: expanded]

Comment: What do you mean by "size of the scroll"?

Comment: I was able to solve my question using this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21428295/resize-expandbar-swt-in-scrolledcomposite

Comment: @greg-449 you have also contributted to that post, so thanks indeed